# Debug error in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I tried to debug C++ file with gdb, but following error message is appeared.

`Unable to 'main.cpp': File not found (file:///c/Users/.../main.cpp)`

But I set the program path in `launch.json` file like this:

`"program": "C:/Users/.../main.exe"`

I think it's because VS Code recognizes **C:** to **c**, but I couldn't find any solutions to fix this issue.

How can I set target program's path correctly?

Comment: Just to improve this question's searchability on google, here is the current error text: "Unable to open 'main.cpp': Unable to read file (Error: file not found ...)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution through asking VS Code GitHub.
If above error message is appeared, add `sourceFileMap` to `launch.json` file.

```
"sourceFileMap": {
    "/c": "C:/"
}
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1546#issuecomment-365368570

Answer (score 1):

Try to write the path in the launch file as:

```
"program": "C:\\Users\\..\\main.exe"
```

Comment: In the article, debugger path was problem but I set it correctly.(`"miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/usr/bin/gdb.exe"`) Nothing has changed.